# Hello Everyone i am trying to make a php table look nicer by implementing a drop down menu between e

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a php table look more nicer by implementing a drop down menu between its rows , my code for creating a table is the following

```
echo "<table class=box  border=1px>
<div id=<wrapper>
<tr>
<th>Zone</th>
<th>Rownumber</th>
</tr>";

echo "<form action=selectsits.php enctype=multipart/form-data method=post>";
while($record=mysql_fetch_array($availablesitsdata) )  {
echo '<tr>';
echo '<select name=cat_id>
<option value="a">aa</option>
<option value="b">bb</option>     
      </select>
    </td>';
echo "<td>" . $record['Zone']  . "</td>";

echo"</tr>";
}
echo "</form>";
```

but the drop down menus are outside the table and not inside. Does anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You havent table close tag. You need a  in your code.

I corrected your code a little bit:

```
echo '<table class="box"  style="border: 1px">'
<div id="wrapper">
<tr>
<th>Zone</th>
<th>Rownumber</th>
</tr>";

    echo "<form action="selectsits.php" enctype=multipart/form-data method=post>";
while($record=mysql_fetch_array($availablesitsdata) )  {
echo '<tr>';
echo '<select name="cat_id">'.
'<option value="a">aa</option>'.
'<option value="b">bb</option>'.
      '</select>'.
    '</td>';
echo "<td>" . $record['Zone']  . "</td>";

echo"</tr>";
}
echo "</form>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</table>";
```

But it is very ugly code.

Comment: Thanks man really appreciate it , what would you advise me to do in order to look better ?

Comment: Use normally the ' and " characters

Comment: Things still aren't balanced.  There's a </td> in the middle that doesn't have a <td> that it balances.

Comment: Firstly try to build the html after it take it the PHP file.